# Fatal Error: Com Class not Found in C:/Xampp/htdocs/../

Tags: php, function, class

Im trying To use COM extension On php.But I get this Error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Coba\tes.php on line 2
```

Im Using XAMPP 1.8.2 with PHP version 5.4.31

I've tried to edit PHP.ini and delete all the semi colon.But Still get the same error.here is my PHP.ini

```
[COM]
; path to a file containing GUIDs, IIDs or filenames of files with TypeLibs
; http://php.net/com.typelib-file
com.typelib_file =

; allow Distributed-COM calls
; http://php.net/com.allow-dcom
com.allow_dcom = true

; autoregister constants of a components typlib on com_load()
; http://php.net/com.autoregister-typelib
com.autoregister_typelib = true

; register constants casesensitive
; http://php.net/com.autoregister-casesensitive
com.autoregister_casesensitive = false

; show warnings on duplicate constant registrations
; http://php.net/com.autoregister-verbose
com.autoregister_verbose = true

; The default character set code-page to use when passing strings to and from COM objects.
; Default: system ANSI code page
com.code_page=
```

Should i Define the com.typelib_file or enable the COM Extension Manually ?

Comment: First, Restart your Xampp Server. And, check once again.

Comment: I have Restart it.It seems that i have to add the extension manually But I got The error 

Warning: com::com(): Type library constant emptyenum is already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\..\..

But When I remove The Extension from PHP.ini its started to saying that COM Class Is Not Found Again.What Should I do?

Comment: So now error is in your code. Can you please show us the error `is already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\..\..` . Edit in your question.

Comment: What Happened @Aditya. Code Working fine now ?